# Does TFS 2018 log outbound connections to gitlab?

Tags: logging, tfs, gitlab

Does TFS 2018 or IIS log outbound connections from TFS server to other endpoints? For example we have an on premise instance of GitLab that one of the team still uses. In the test environment we created a build that uses the GitLab repo. It's my understanding that that type of build "polls" the GitLab repo for changes. If that communication logged somewhere in TFS for troubleshooting purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Request History` of Services endpoint in TFS2018 meet your needs?

[image]

If this does not meet your needs, can you specify what the outbound connections log refers to?

Comment: I didn't know about the first option, Request History of the service. I deleted the one that was causing me issues 2 days prior so I'm not sure if it would have been what would have pointed me toward that.  I opened the activity log page and exported it and tried to filter on my user ID and that did not show any connections to the GitLab server.  I'm not sure what you mean about "get the activity log through tbl_Command table"